# Unable to install CUDA with VS 2012 Express?

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I need to install CUDA 5.5. I do not have VS full version so I installed the Express version 2012. But now, CUDA says this.

[image]

I found many posts in SO who installed this with VS Express 2012. What's the matter here? I need to install CUDA and work with java `rootbeer` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that CUDA 5.5 installer bundles Nsight Visual Studio plugin, which [requires](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements) professional version or better. Despite that it should be still possible to install CUDA by choosing custom installation deselecting that plugin and then compile GPU programs, however only with 32-bit builds (AFAIR it is possible to build 64-bit targets with Express Edition, but you need appriopriate Windows SDK).

Note that Visual Studio and CUDA do not support Java language, for that you more likely need some Java's binding and suitable IDE, for example [jcuda](http://www.jcuda.org/) and Eclipse with JDT.

Comment: rootbeer is a Java on CUDA library also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So does this only support VS 2012 full version?

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess: In short: for plugin yes, for everything else including `nvcc` compiler support no.

Comment: I installed the full version of VS 2012 professional. what did you mean by `for everything else including nvcc compiler support no` ?

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess: I mean that there is no need for better version if you don't need Nsight integration i.e. debugging and profiling. It should be possible to compile and build .cu programs, see my answer.

Comment: I installed the professional version. According to your answer, I am good I guess :)